# Any potential issues with changing the owner of a symmetric key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We're doing a security audit on a database I support, and there's one old, obsolete user who can't be removed because he owns a symmetric key in the database. The symmetric key is being used to encrypt user passwords.

Are there any potential implications to changing the owner of the symmetric key to `dbo`? We wouldn't be changing anything else about the key, just issuing `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SYMMETRIC KEY::PasswordKey TO dbo`.

Comment: Restore this database onto a development server, make the change, then test it against your actual code base.

Comment: For sure, but thought I'd gather some knowledge about the change first. If there are obvious reasons why this would be a disaster that I'm unaware of, it would be nice to know that and save myself the trouble of finding it out on my own!

Comment: Theoretically, changing the owner to be the database owner should probably not be a problem.  As long as the code that uses the certificate can still access it, then ok.  That's a pretty big if since we have no idea about the system in question.  Hence the advice to test it.